# Using AutoMapper to map multiple collection properties of the same type

Tags: automapper

I need to map to properties that are both collections of objects of the same type.

For example:

Destination:

```
public class MyNewObject
{
    Collection TypeCollection1 { get; set; }
    Collection TypeCollection2 { get; set; }
}

public class MyType
{
    string Field1 { get; set; }
    string Field2 { get; set; }
}
```

Source:

```
public class MyLegacyObject
{
    Collection LegacyCollection1 { get; set; }
    Collection LegacyCollection2 { get; set; }
}

public class MyLegacyType
{
    string OldField1 { get; set; }
    string OldField2 { get; set; }
}
```

For non-collections, I'm used to doing something like this:

```
Mapper.CreateMap()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.TypeCollection1, opt => opt.MapFrom( 
        src => new Collection 
        {
            // is there some kind of ForEach thing I can do???
            Field1 = src.OldField1,
            Field2 = src.OldField2
            ??? // this obviously doesn't work because these are the properties on MyType, not the collection
        }));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Mapper.CreateMap<MyLegacyType, MyType>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Field1, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.OldField1))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Field2, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.OldField2));
Mapper.CreateMap<MyLegacyObject, MyNewObject>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.TypeCollection1, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.LegacyCollection1))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.TypeCollection2, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.LegacyCollection2))
```

I think I solved my own issue.  This should do it.